# How to create a numpy array filled with differences of elements of another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array X. I need to create another array (say Y) of the same size, which has elements

`Y[i] = X[i+1]-X[i-1]`

Can I do that without looping over array elements?

Comment: What's `Y[0]` (`i-1 = -1`)? Can you add some small sample input and desired output?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html

Comment: @pault, Y[0] and Y[-1] will be handled separately (in fact I just assign fixed values to those two elements).

Comment: In that case, @Jello's solution should work.

Comment: @mamun, diff is nice, but it gives differences between neighbouring elements, while what I need is "leapfrog" difference: not between 2nd and 1st elements (or, say 6th and 5th), but rather between 3rd and 1st ones (7th and 5th, so on).

Comment: @pault, yes, Jello's solution does exactly what I need (but at the cost of creating two additional arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make new arrays with shifted values and then subtract them from one another. Something like this:

```
import numpy as np

X  = np.arange(10)
X1 = np.roll(X,-1) #right shift
X2 = np.roll(X,1)  #left shift
Y  = X1 - X2
```

Comment: this one is perfect. Going to use it if there's no builtin method for that thing.